# What is the proper way to create library files with a Makefile? [C]

Tags: c, unix, makefile

I am making my first Makefile for a simple shell system. I need to make library files but for some reason the library section is not working out. In the error message it says the library files do no exist (obviously).

Am I missing something obvious that could fix this? Also, is there any other way I can make this Makefile more efficient?

```
# Beginning of Makefile

OBJS = obj/shutil.o obj/parser.o obj/sshell.o obj/history.o obj/hash_table.o obj/variables.o
HEADER_FILES = include/shell.h include/parser.h include/history.h include/hash_table.h include/variables.h
EXECUTABLE = sshell
LIBS = lib/libshell.so lib/libparser.so lib/libhistory.so lib/libhash_table.so lib/libvariables.so
LIBCFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) -D_REENTRANT -fPIC
CFLAGS = -Wall
CC = gcc
# End of configuration options

#What needs to be built to make all files and dependencies
all: $(EXECUTABLE)

#Create the main executable
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJS) $(LIBS)
    $(CC) -o $(EXECUTABLE) obj/sshell.o -Llib -lparser -lshell -lhistory -lhash_table -lvariables

#Create the library files
$(LIBS): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LIBCFLAGS) -shared -o $(LIBS) $(OBJS)

#Recursively build object files
obj/%.o: src/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I./include/ -c $< -o $@

#Define dependencies for objects based on header files
#We are overly conservative here, parser.o should depend on parser.h only
$(OBJS) : $(HEADER_FILES)

clean:
    -rm -f $(EXECUTABLE) obj/*.o lib/*.so lib/*.a
    -rm -f .sshell_history.txt

run: $(EXECUTABLE)
    (export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=lib; ./$(EXECUTABLE))

# End of Makefile
```

Thanks!
-Lily Banks

**Edit:**

Before I tried to change it, here is what I had with regards to library files.

```
$(LIBS): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -shared -o lib/libparser.a obj/parser.o
    $(CC) -shared -o lib/libshell.a obj/shutil.o
    $(CC) -shared -o lib/libhistory.a obj/history.o
    $(CC) -shared -o lib/libhash_table.a obj/hash_table.o
    $(CC) -shared -o lib/libvariables.a obj/variables.o
```

The problem with this was that it compiled each file five times which is not efficient at all. So what I was trying to do was do it all in one go.

**Edit2:**

```
#Create the library files
lib/libparser.so: obj/parser.o
    $(CC) $(LIBFLAGS) -shared lib/libparser.a -o $@

lib/libshell.so: obj/shutil.o
    $(CC) $(LIBFLAGS) -shared lib/libshell.a -o $@

lib/libhistory.so: obj/history.o
    $(CC) $(LIBFLAGS) -shared lib/libhistory.a -o $@

lib/libhash_table.so: obj/hash_table.o
    $(CC) $(LIBFLAGS) -shared lib/libhash_table.a -o $@

lib/variables.so: obj/variables.o
    $(CC) $(LIBFLAGS) -shared lib/libvariables.a -o $@
```

Unfortunately, here is the error I am getting:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `lib/libvariables.so', needed by `sshell'.  Stop.
```

Thoughts?

**Edit3:**

```
#Create the library files
lib/libparser.so: obj/parser.o
    $(CC) $(LIBFLAGS) -shared $^ -o lib/libparser.a

lib/libshell.so: obj/shutil.o
    $(CC) $(LIBFLAGS) -shared $^ -o lib/libshell.a

lib/libhistory.so: obj/history.o
    $(CC) $(LIBFLAGS) -shared $^ -o lib/libhistory.a

lib/libhash_table.so: obj/hash_table.o
    $(CC) $(LIBFLAGS) -shared $^ -o lib/libhash_table.a

lib/libvariables.so: obj/variables.o
    $(CC) $(LIBFLAGS) -shared $^ -o lib/libvariables.a
```

This works but is there anything else I need to change? Thanks

Comment: In your edit you are telling make to recompile all the libraries whenever one of the object files are updated. You need one target for each library.

Comment: Yes, I took your advice and I tried something but it is not working. I'll edit it again with what I have now. Thanks

Comment: You have lib/variables.so and not lib/libvariables.so

Comment: Embarassing, sorry. Here is the error I am getting now: `gcc: lib/libvariables.a: No such file or directory
gcc: no input files`

Comment: Do you have the static library lib/libvariables.a? I would expect you would have to substitute lib/libvariables.a with obj/variables.o. Or even better $^

Comment: Yea, I think I had it in the wrong order. I think it works now, I'll update with a final edit. Let me know what you think.

Comment: substitute lib/libvariables.a with lib/libvariables.so because you are trying to compile a shared library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need one set of object files for each library. And the -o flag only takes one argument which is the output file, you are trying to output all the library files which you cannot do with one invocation of gcc.

You need to do something like:

```
lib/libshell.so: obj/sshell.o
    $(CC) $(LIBFLAGS) -shared obj/sshell.o -o lib/libshell.so

lib/libparser.so: obj/parser.o
    $(CC) $(LIBFLAGS) -shared obj/parser.o -o lib/libparser.so
```

for each of the libraries.

Answer (score 2):

This line is completely wrong:

```
$(LIBS): $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(LIBCFLAGS) -shared -o $(LIBS) $(OBJS)
```

If you expanded all the variables, this line would look like this (adding line breaks for clarity):

```
lib/libshell.so lib/libparser.so lib/libhistory.so lib/libhash_table.so lib/libvariables.so: \
            obj/shutil.o obj/parser.o   obj/sshell.o obj/history.o obj/hash_table.o obj/variables.o
        gcc -Wall -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -shared -o lib/libshell.so lib/libparser.so lib/libhistory.so \
            lib/libhash_table.so lib/libvariables.so obj/shutil.o obj/parser.o obj/sshell.o obj/history.o \
            obj/hash_table.o obj/variables.o
```

Which, it should be clear, is very not right.  It's so not right I can't even really tell what you're trying to accomplish.  Do you really want to create one shared library for every `.o` file, where each shared library contains a single `.o`?  If so why are you trying to link both the `.o` files AND the shared libraries into a single executable?

If you explain what you are really trying to do, at a higher level, we can help.

Comment: ill edit my main post with what I had before I guess I should be more clear.